# Playing videos fullscreen in chrome causes all chrome windows to freeze if attempting to exit FullScreen

Tags: video, google-chrome, fullscreen

The following problem is recent: maybe a few weeks. I am on Mojave on an MBPro 2015 with retina.  it seems *any* video when played in FullScreen will cause the behavior described in the title. This happens for:

- Youtube when exiting while video still playing (always)
- Youtube when exiting when video is paused (frequently)
- Youtube when simply trying to switch back to other non-full screen windows - but not trying to exit Chrome fullscreen window:  (frequently)
- Whatever espn is using for videos (always)
- I did not try it with Quicktime.

Here is Chrome info:

[image]

I have tried disabling hardware acceleration: that is simply a disaster - causing chrome to crawl (briefly) and then freeze.

**Update**  This full-screen freeze is happening in **completely different** types of Apps: including *Intellij* - which has nothing to do with videos.  This is something recent and is clearly a **Mojave** issue.  I am on `10.14.4`

Comment: This seems like a Chrome issue.  Did you try in a different browser like Safari or Firefox?

Comment: It *is* a chrome issue: does that invalidate the question? Should it be moved to a different site?

Comment: Not entirely, but you are much more likely to get a resolution from Google support.  If it’s a bug in their software, there’s really nothing we can do.  Personally, I solved all my chrome issues by using a different browser.

Comment: @Allan  The SE family of sites welcomes vendor-specific questions.  I go directly to vendor support in targeted instances: I generally first check if others have noticed issues and have solutions.  Dropping chrome?  Not a good choice - for many reasons out of scope of this question.